# Doubts regarding Past perfect tense

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence grammatically correct -

1. When I hadn't seen you for a while , I started to get worried .

Comment: Grammatical, quite common, but purists might like to rephrase (no doubt to something at least approaching the rarefied).  The hiccup here is that 'when' is usually used with punctive events, and here the time of 'not having seen someone' is open-ended. Perhaps seeing this as a welcome shortening of << (1') When the moment came when I decided I hadn't seen you for a length of time that had become unusually long, I started to get worried >> helps.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth What is a "punctive" event? Do you mean to say that 'when is used mostly with semalfactive verbs?

Comment: Following @EdwinAshworth's thought about what purists might prefer, the sentence might be improved by replacing "When" with "After": "After I hadn't seen you for a while, I started to get worried." This would solve the temporal ambiguity of _when_ and place the "worry" solidly _after_ the indeterminate span of time indicated by the past perfect and the phrase "for a while."

Comment: Might be improved by rephrasing as: When *I realized* I hadn't seen you *in* a while, I started to get worried. The verb tenses are correct. But stating *I realized* makes this a particular moment WHEN this happens.

Comment: @40475 Punctive: as GArthurBrown says, 'happening at a particular moment' (or what is often approximated to as such). 'Punctive' covers both semelfactives and iteratives. A variant is 'punctual', but the default meaning complicates.